# Ionic - routing issue/button link

Tags: routes, ionic-framework

I'm writing my first ionic app and hit a little problem.

I have a tab interface that initially has a login screen, once you login you can select the tabs, on one tab screen I have a list of items that you need to click to show further options, but I can't quite get these links to work, so I think my ui-sref is a bit wrong... looking for a second pair of eyes! Its the linking to a profile view that I'm struggling with, below is my app.js with the routing and the page with the links on below.

```
app.js
.state('login', {
url: '/login',
templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
controller:'loginCtrl'
```

})

```
 // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

.state('tab.profile', {
url: '/profile',
views: {
  'profile': {
    templateUrl: 'templates.tab.profile.html',
    controller: 'profileCtrl'
  }
}
```

})

Then the list page:

```
 <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" class="viewer-panel">

        <div class="list">
            <div class="item item-divider">
            Profile
          </div>
              <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="tab.profile">
                <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                View profile
              </a>
```

Comment: Is the templateUrl correct for tab.profile?  Maybe it should be 'templates/tab.profile.html' based on the abstract route's templateUrl.

Comment: Yes I did have it set to that templateUrl too but it still didn't work, I feel like the ui-Sref is incorrect but again I've tried various options #/tab/profile being one